# Is it possible to have multiple ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an html element have multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

Is it possible multiple id ? Can I use it like this ?

```
$("#example" + " #example2")
```

Html

```
<section id="example example2"></section>
```

Comment: Use classes instead. Personally, in most cases I don't use Ids at all on elements, except for containers with unique ids if multiple copies of a form exist on a page or if you need to pass a target element to an ajax call or something similar. If a set of elements has no classes or ids one can still traverse through the DOM with jQuery quite easily.

Comment: I fail to see why you would need 2 id's. Why would you do anything like this `$("#example" + " #example2")`, when both of these id's target the same element?

Comment: In fact I want to do my second example but i cant ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to do in your second example. Would you mind explaining what you are trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: look http://jsfiddle.net/Dymxu/ i don't understand how can i use this (firstLoadedHtml + " #content") how is this code html ?

Comment: That is my point. I don't understand what you want to do, because what you have done, doesn't really make sense. So, try to explain what you are trying to do instead.

Comment: I would like to make it http://bramvanroy.be/sectionLoaderTest/ but I can't find this html http://bramvanroy.be/sectionLoaderTest/js/sections.js I don't understand (firstLoadedHtml + " #content") this code html ?

Comment: Now I understand what that is trying to accomplish. Your example was way out of context. He is using jquery load method http://api.jquery.com/load/ - What is done in that code is basically the same as this: `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');` In that site you linked, the "ajax/test.html" is taken from the links href, and "#container" is a static id.

Comment: so what is this html code ? <section id="content" class="ajax/test.html"> ?

Comment: Why would you do something like that?

Comment: This code also takes a page from the outside ?

Comment: No. That is just a `section` with id `content` and a class `ajax/test.html`, which doesn't make any sense :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** It's not possible according to [XHTML 1.0 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10)

> HTML 4 defined the name attribute for the elements a, applet, form,
>   frame, iframe, img, and map. HTML 4 also introduced the id attribute.
>   Both of these attributes are designed to be used as fragment
>   identifiers.
>
> In XML, fragment identifiers are of type ID, and there can only be a
>   single attribute of type ID per element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the
>   id attribute is defined to be of type ID. In order to ensure that
>   XHTML 1.0 documents are well-structured XML documents, XHTML 1.0
>   documents MUST use the id attribute when defining fragment identifiers
>   on the elements listed above. See the HTML Compatibility Guidelines
>   for information on ensuring such anchors are backward compatible when
>   serving XHTML documents as media type text/html.
>
> Note that in XHTML 1.0, the name attribute of these elements is
>   formally deprecated, and will be removed in a subsequent version of
>   XHTML.

But according to W3 It's a **YES**

[W3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors)

> If an element has multiple ID attributes, all of them must be treated
>   as IDs for that element for the purposes of the ID selector. Such a
>   situation could be reached using mixtures of xml:id, DOM3 Core, XML
>   DTDs, and namespace-specific knowledge.

Common usage

> ID's are single use and are only applied to one element. They are used
>   to identify a single element. Classes can be used more than once. They
>   can therefore be applied to more than one element, and more than once
>   per element

Comment: Is it true that my second example ?

Answer (score 4):

You should not use multiple IDs. If you need that use classes.

Comment: so can I use attr href and id ? so look i will edit now

Comment: @CnzAdm No, multiple Ids is never valid, regardless of the preceding elements. Use a class instead.

Comment: Is it true that my second example ?

Comment: You can't use multiple IDs at any cost.

Answer (score 0):

According to XHTML 1.0 Spec, no. you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not (i tried it on JS fiddle), why on Earth would you need to have multiple IDs... I'm sure there's some much more elegant solution to your problem... can you specify it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. ID always refer to uniqueness.