# php - Loop output in two diffrent divs?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to output my sql rows on each side of a line, without breaking the line.
Forexample the html/css code i would like to end up with is something like this:

```
<div id='container'>

 <div style='float:left;'>
   Even loops here..
 </div>

 <div id='line' style='float:left;'>
 </div>

 <div style='float:right;'>
   Uneven loops here..
 </div>

 <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to output the sql rows in two diffrent divs?

Comment: Having that `id='line'` element inside a loop is not a good idea.

Comment: @techfoobar reason for not a good idea?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - obviously, the page will end up with multiple elements with `id='line'` - Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: Lol Techfoobar. Id's are used when you want them displayed more than once on a page.. you just can't merge multiple id's into one element (or well, yes you can, but it's not a good idea)

Comment: Classes are used if you want to display something more then once.  That is some very basic html and css knowledge.

Comment: Seems the easy way would be to fetch all the query rows to an array, split up the array into two and then loop each array in each div.

Answer (score 0):

Just write two different queries or fetch all rows and put it in an array and filter them like this:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $array[] = $row['number'];
```

OR JUST USE THE $row as an array to filter
    }

```
print_r(array_filter($array, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array, "even"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<div id='container'>

 <div style='float:left;'>
   <?php
   $ct_row = 0;
   foreach ($array as $one) :
   if (($ct_row % 2) == 0) {
        echo $one;
   }
   $ct_row++;
   endforeach;
   ?>
 </div>

 <div id='line' style='float:left;'>
 </div>

 <div style='float:right;'>
   <?php
   $ct_row = 0;
   foreach ($array as $one) :
   if (($ct_row % 2) != 0) {
        echo $one;
   }
   $ct_row++;
   endforeach;
   ?>
 </div>

 <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```