# Add multiple unique ids to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a second unique id to an element.

I use this to generate new ids

```
var id = 1;
function getNextId()
{
    return ++id;
}
```

Then I am doing this

```
$('<div id="content '" + getNextId() +"'" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
```

But I am getting an `Uncaight SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

How can I add multiple ids where the second is a unique one?

(I am remove the first id on a click, so I'm ok with leaving #content there)

Multiple ids on an element have been discussed in here: [Can an html element have multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

Comment: It's looking like first of all `$('<div id="content 'newId'" + getNextId() +"' class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');` Should read something more like: `$('<div id="content ' + newId + '"' + getNextId() + ' class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');` But in addition, what is `newId`? It's hard to tell just what your variables are in your selector as you've got a good mixture of single and double quotes. Can you make sure those are where you think they should be?

Comment: Your quotes are wrong.

Comment: newId is a string I am placing before the unique id i generate otherwise i would have a number

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. Also, element IDs cannot have spaces in them.

Comment: An element can only have one ID.  If you are using XHTML, you can add a namespaced `ID` attribute, but that's not *technically* an ID, it's a different attribute.

Comment: i read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: @rob.m: Check out this comment from that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids#comment14501781_5685221

Comment: right yes. dreams ended right here lol :) thanks

Answer (score 6):

> How can I add multiple ids where the second is a unique one?

You can't.

You can't have multiple IDs on one element. You get zero or one ID per element, and that is it. If you want to add additional things to select an element by, you can use classes.

Your syntax error is due to some very confused quotation marks; I suspect you wanted to do this:

```
$('<div id="content newId' + getNextId() + '" class="span6"></div>')
```

producing something like `<div id="content newId3">`, which can't work. You're not giving it two IDs, you're giving it one ID with a space in it, which is an invalid ID:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: therefore taking the fact we can actually have 2 different ids, you are suggesting to output 2 completly id= rather than concatenate the 2 into one id= as otherwise i'd get what you are syaing, 1 id name with space in it?

Comment: basically this right? $('<div id="content" id= "' + getNextId() + '" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');

Comment: @rob.m: You *CANNOT* have 2 different IDs, and you also can't define the same attribute twice.  He was just pointing out a syntax error in your code.  You *can* do this in XHTML: `<p id="foo" xml:id="bar">`, but only because one is namespaced.

Comment: @rob.m **No**. What I'm saying is you  **can't do it**. You **cannot have two IDs**. It's impossible. There **is no valid syntax for doing so**.

Comment: yes i got what you mean, i could use xml:id="bar", read the link on the comment

Comment: but even tho i could use that, is pointless for my case. I it's a fail my question unfortunatly :( Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `'a'b` isn't valid JavaScipt. Try `'a' + b`
2. Whitespace characters aren't allowed in HTML ids. And even if they were, all characters in the `id` attribute would make up the ID, so you can't assign more than one ID to an element. Use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like:

```
$('<div id="content '+ newId + getNextId() +'" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
```

I bet that is more right

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('<div id="content-' + getNextId() + '" class="span6"></div>').appendTo('.new');
```

Comment: i need to keep newId as it is a string I am placing befroe the enwly created uniqe id, otherwise it'd be a number

Answer (score 0):

I think a pretty good start would be to add a `+` there.

```
'<div id="id-' my_id_var '"></div>'
```

Just isn't going to work.

```
"<div id=\"id-" + getNextID() + "\"></div>"
```

Will work just fine, though.

Second issue, each element gets ***1*** ID.
The point is that an ID is given to make an element *uniquely-identifiable*.
Why do you want the element to be uniquely identifiable *twice*?

There are lots of other ways of doing this.

First, you have `class`.
If you are working with objects which need similar states ("selected", "news-article", "user-interactive"), use classes.

Then, you have `data-` attributes.

```
<div id="player_1"
     class="player-character"
     data-health="42"
     data-x="320"
     data-y="240"
     data-speed="5"
    ><img src="..."
></div>
```

Then in JS, you could do something like:

```
var player_1 = document.getElementById("player_1");
player_1.dataset.health;  // "42"
```

These values are supported as far back as IE8, I think.
If you want to go further than that, then instead of using `.dataset`, you use `.setAttribute("data-" + field_name, value)`

If you're using jQuery, then it handles ALL of that for you, anyway.

So with all of these options, why do you want 2 ids per one element?