# Jquery ID selector doesnt work when multiple IDs are given

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have just the `#index` on my body element, the length method gives me the correct answer of `1`. But if I have a second ID on this body element the length method gives me `0`. Whats wrong with that?

```
$("#index").length
```

You can test it here. Just remove the `.removeme` from the body tag and try the command in the developer console again.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RmqsS/2/show/

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You can't have two IDs, and an ID cannot contain spaces.

Comment: Why two IDs? I don't think that is correct. Class can be many but not IDs.

Comment: Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs in the same page. Change that to a class instead

Comment: you're not supposed to have the same id twice. use class instead

Comment: A HTML element should only have one ID:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: [This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: In the rare scenario where one doesn't have access to the source HTML e.g when building proxies, in order to target an element that had multiple ids this css selector can be used [id="one two three"']. The string literal of the id attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RmqsS/3/)

You cannot have `multiple id's` for a element.

> because the browser will only render the first one

```
$("#inp").val($("#index").length); //sets value 1
              ^ //add $ here
```

Read

[Can a HTML element have multiple unique ID attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936132/can-a-html-element-have-multiple-unique-id-attributes)

[id attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

ID 's are meant to be unique identifiers for elements. If you want to have multiple identifiers on an element. use classes.

Documentation:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 0):

An id is unique.
A tag should have only one id and a id can't be used multiple times.