# Reference multiple words in css

Tags: css

I have a wordpress page and i see that one of the items that i would like to style has an id of `wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  textboxtest`. how can i reference something like that in css since it has spaces between the words?

Comment: If its an ID you start it with a # if its a class you start it with a .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have one class but multiple classes. To reference that in CSS

```
.wpb_text_column.wpb_content_element.textboxtest {
          /* CSS code */
}
```

IDs are unique and a div can contain only one.

Answer (score 1):

The space between the words makes it into separate ids.  Your browser will only target the first id as you cannot target multiple ids (see description here: [Can a HTML element have multiple unique ID attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936132/can-a-html-element-have-multiple-unique-id-attributes))

You should be able to use the following, assuming there are no other IDs titled "wpb_text_column":

```
#wpb_text_column{
  //your CSS here;
}
```

If you are able to add a class to that item you can be specific by targeting that id and concatenating it with your class name to ensure that only that item will be modified with your CSS.