# Ajax script wont get called on Actionlink click

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Im trying to call this script once the ajax link is clicked but for some reason it won't call #myLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteRecord", new { id = item.JPAppId }, new { @class = "fa fa-trash", id = "myLink" })


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myLink").click(function (event) {
    console.log("Method called");
});
```

Comment: You're not included `event.preventDefault()` before calling `console.log` - the default behavior is using `href` attribute to redirect into specified URL.

Comment: you have 2 id? id = item.JPAppId and  id = "myLink" read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936132/can-a-html-element-have-multiple-unique-id-attributes/16936265

Comment: @YuukkaLimson The `{ id = item.JPAppId }` is used for `routeValues`, and the latter is used for `htmlAttributes`, so that the URL will look as `DeleteRecord?id=[someidvalue]` or `DeleteRecord/[someidvalue]`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto not sure about the overloads but can the op post the rendered html also?