# Two buttons conflicting with each other HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons that call the same JavaScript function but with a different argument. When I test them independently, they work fine. However, when they're together, only the "next" button works. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
if (fbResults.collection.links[p].prompt == "Previous") {
    var linkBack = "" + fbResults.collection.links[p].href;
    nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += "<a id=\"prevBtn\" name=\"prevBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\">Previous</a>";
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").onclick = function () { findImages(linkBack); };
}
if (fbResults.collection.links[p].prompt == "Next") {
    var linkForward = "" + fbResults.collection.links[p].href;
    nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += "<a id=\"nextBtn\" name=\"nextBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\" >Next</a>";
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").onclick = function () { findImages(linkForward); };
}
```

Comment: Include more code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your first assigned a-tag node:

```
nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += 
"<a id=\"prevBtn\" name=\"prevBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\">Previous</a>";
```

is creating new nodes. So at the second time

```
nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += 
"<a id=\"nextBtn\" name=\"nextBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\" >Next</a>";
```

it is the same as

```
nextBtnDiv.innerHTML = 

"<a id=\"prevBtn\" name=\"prevBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\">Previous</a>" 
+ "<a id=\"nextBtn\" name=\"nextBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\" >Next</a>";
```

but now you are removing the first assigned node and its listeners

It is better to create a node and append it like:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
// set a attr ...
nextBtnDiv.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

## A better way to do it

Read on if you want specifics about why you're getting this behavior.  If you want a quick solution, try creating and appending DOM elements instead of directly manipulating `innerHTML`:

```
const prevBtn = document.createElement("a");
prevBtn.id = "prevBtn";
prevBtn.name = "prevBtn";
prevBtn.class = "button1";
prevBtn.type = "button";
prevBtn.innerHTML = "Previous";

const nextBtn = document.createElement("a");
nextBtn.id = "nextBtn";
nextBtn.name = "nextBtn";
nextBtn.class = "button1";
nextBtn.type = "button";
nextBtn.innerHTML = "Next";

for (let p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
  if (fbResults.collection.links[p].prompt == "Previous") {
      var linkBack = "" + fbResults.collection.links[p].href;
      prevBtn.onclick = function () { findImages(linkBack); };
      nextBtnDiv.appendChild(prevBtn);
  }
  if (fbResults.collection.links[p].prompt == "Next") {
      var linkForward = "" + fbResults.collection.links[p].href;
      nextBtn.onclick = function () { findImages(linkForward); };
      nextBtnDiv.appendChild(nextBtn);
  }
}
```

---

## *Why* your code behaves the way it does

A few things going on here.  First, `type="button"` is not a valid type in an `<a>` tag.  [It is for describing the media type you're linking to.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_type.asp)  So you would usually use a `<button>` for that type of function call (which I'm assuming is for pagination).

Second, when playing around with your code I realized I made a mistake that you might have made as well: I gave the `<div>` surrounding the buttons an `id="nextBtn"`, then called the variable I found using that `nextBtnDiv`, like you did.  The problem with that is that HTML expects `id`s to be unique, and when you use `document.getElementById` to get an element in the DOM, you will get the first element that matches that `id` at best, and undefined behavior at worst. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936132/can-a-html-element-have-multiple-unique-id-attributes/16936265) for more info on that.

So if *both* anchor tags end up triggering the "Next" link, it is because you're probably giving the whole `<div>` (which contains both buttons), rather than the next button itself, the `onclick` handler.

Finally, if you fix that issue, you'll still see that your previous button does nothing when clicked.  Here's why:

```
nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += "<a id=\"nextBtn\" name=\"nextBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\" >Next</a>";
```

This line basically means "make `nextBtnDiv.innerHTML` be equal to `nextBtnDiv.innerHTML` *plus* `"<a id=\"nextBtn\" name=\"nextBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\" >Next</a>"`".  The problem is a bit tricky.  It is **recreating** both `<a>` tags, *not just adding* the "next" one, to the `<div>`.  That's because of the `+=` semantics and how they work, but basically once you have *new* buttons the previous one gets overwritten and you lose the `onclick` handler you attached to it.

One of the ways to get around this is to *recreate* the "previous" click behavior once you create the behavior for the "next" button.  Like in the following snippet:

```js
const nextBtnDiv = document.getElementById("nextBtnDiv");
const fbResults = {
  collection: {
    links: [
      { prompt: "Previous", href: "previous" },
      { prompt: "Next", href: "next" },
    ],
  },
};

for (let p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
  if (fbResults.collection.links[p].prompt == "Previous") {
      var linkBack = "" + fbResults.collection.links[p].href;
      nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += "<a id=\"prevBtn\" name=\"prevBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\">Previous</a>";
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").onclick = function () { findImages(linkBack); };
  }
  if (fbResults.collection.links[p].prompt == "Next") {
      var linkForward = "" + fbResults.collection.links[p].href;
      nextBtnDiv.innerHTML += "<a id=\"nextBtn\" name=\"nextBtn\" class=\"button1\" type=\"button\" >Next</a>";
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").onclick = function () { findImages(linkBack); };
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").onclick = function () { findImages(linkForward); };
  }
}

function findImages(link) { console.log(`Clicked ${link} button`); }
```

```html
<div id="nextBtnDiv"></div>
```