# ng-repeat, directive and on-click. How do they combine?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to trap on-click event of button. The id of button is dynamically generated inside the ng-repeat.

```
.set(ng-repeat='button in ['4', '3' , '2', '1' ]')
   button(id='{{$index}}') button {{button}}
```

Button 4 
  Button 3 
   Button 2 
   Button 1

Above where do i put the `my-dir` directive attribute/class?

```
.my-dir
  .set ...
```

The above does not work.

and

```
.my-dir.set ...
```

executes the link function multiple times.

/* below code in greater details, if above statement is not clear enough */

Directive is

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {

  alert('inside linkFn');
  $('button').on('click', function() { alert('button clicked');});
} 

  return {
    restrict: 'C', 
    link: linkFn
  }
});
```

using `ng-repeat` the class `my-dir` can be put either in the scope of ng-repeat or outside it

case 1: my-dir is outside scope of ng-repeat

```
.my-dir
  .set(ng-repeat='button in buttons')
    button(id='id{{$index}}') {{item}}
```

now the above code `$('.set').on('click', function() { alert('button clicked');});` does not get executed!

case 2: my-dir is inside ng-repeat

(in controller) `$scope.buttons=['4', '3', '2', '1']`

```
.set(ng-repeat='button in buttons').my-dir
    button(id='id{{$index}}') button {{item}}
```

now when you press `button 4` "button clicked" shows up in alert box 4 times. For `button 3` 3 times and so on.

Comment: Why can you not use `ng-click`?  Also, ID's should not contains spaces, it is not like class where it can have multiple (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

Comment: for DOM manipulation, Directives are recommended. I want to change css upon click of button. I am not using space in `ids`

Comment: Sorry about that, the formatting was off and it appeared that the id field contained spaces.

Comment: If you are using Jade, consider adding corresponding tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with setting the directive on the wrapping element is that the directive will run before the `ng-repeat` has unrolled.  So there are no buttons in the element when the `on` method is called.  You can use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method a little differently to allow it to be more like the old jquery [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. Apply it to the parent element and pass an optional selector(in your case, `'button'`) to tell it what elements to trigger on.  This is also good for when buttons are added and removed.

```
$(element).on('click', 'button', function () {
    // do something here.
    alert($(this).text() + ' clicked');
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="myDir">
        <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" id="{{button}}">Button {{button}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).directive('myDir', function () {
    var linkFn = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).on('click', 'button', function () {
            alert($(this).text() + ' clicked');
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: linkFn
    }
});

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.buttons = ['4', '3', '2', '1'];
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JjB3B/

Comment: `$(element).on('click', 'button', function () {` is brilliant. Thanks @thesharpieone! you rock!

Comment: Shame the selector parameters are not supported by angular's jqlite implementation