# Fix Javascript Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'resizable'

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am working on the captioning project and I faced this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'resizable'

It is still letting me know that there is no element with the id "resizable"

I attempted to add it. But an element cannot have more than one ID

So what you attempted to do is not valid HTML. An element can have more than one class, but not more than one ID.

I am stuck! What do I do to solve this?

```
            <html>

            <head>
                <title>HTML5 included Javascript....</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

                <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" /-->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

            </head>

            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select class="form-control" id="options">
                                    <optgroup label="Caption">
                                        <option value="0">Off</option>
                                        <option value="1">1 line</option>
                                        <option selected value="2">2 Lines</option>
                                        <option value="3">3 lines</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Transcript">
                                        <option value="off2">Off</option>
                                        <option value="4 line">4 Lines</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <button class="btn" id="returnPosition" type="button">CC return to Original</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div id="container" class="video-container text-center">
                        <video id="video" width="930" height="500" controls autoplay>
                            <!-- removed: controls -->
                            <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="caption.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                            <source src="caption.webm" type="video/webm">
                        </video>
                        <div id="subtitle draggable resizable" class="subtitle"></div>
                        <div class="well well-sm">
                            <button class="btn" id="rewind5" type="button">5 sec rewind</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="negative3" type="button">-3.0x</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="negative2" type="button">-2.0x</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="negative" type="button">-1.5x</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="normal" type="button">&#x25BA</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="speed" type="button">1.5x</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="speed2" type="button">2.0x</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="speed3" type="button">3.0x</button>
                            <button class="btn" id="forward5" type="button">5 sec fast forward</button>
                        </div>

                        <textarea class="form-control" id="scroll" id="testxml" rows="4" style="display:none;" class="form-control"></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                <!--script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script-->
                <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/player.js"></script>

                <script>
                    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
                    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
                </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Link: http://ge.tt/5CxOdjy/v/0

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: too long by 227 characters

Comment: The intention is adding draggable and resizable functionality to captions

Comment: Getting the error in the Google Chrome console
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'resizable' ccFinal.html:73
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give more details as to your intention, but it depends on your purpose.  You could easily use a class of resizable or even use a data- attribute.  An id is supposed to be a unique identifier, so why would you want more than one? The id may also be used by the end-user's stylesheet, so you do not want to replace it.  Adding a custom data- attribute or class will handle both of these issues nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to include the dragresize_commented.js file in ccFinal.html.

Comment: Make resizable and draggable as class. You already know that an element can only have one id.

Comment: Can you provide the example?

Comment: <div  class="subtitle draggable resizable"></div> $(".resizable" ).resizable(); $( ".draggable" ).draggable();

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything to should really sort out your ID's you should not have multiple ones on an element there is no need and its against the XHML specs

see: 
[Can an html element have multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

once you have done this try again just using the one unique id and follow the jQuery example and it should all work fine