# Display a div child with same id via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div> 
      <div id="Container1" >
         <div id="Container1">  
         <object>.....</object>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div onclick="appear()" id="child-2">
      <div id="child-of-child"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've put the CSS bellow to stop display the first child of div#parent and I'm trying to display with a reaction via JavaScript.

CSS

```
div#parent div:first-child div:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

How can I display the the second div#Container1 also?
Because if I use the code bellow, it displays only the first div#Container1.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appear() {
document.getElementById("Container1").document.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elements can't have duplicate IDs.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids - javascript will hence only select the first element.  Think about using classes instead.

Comment: I aggree, but I don't have permission to change that. In that case is there any solution? Otherwise I could fix it very easily.

Comment: @richieahb Just for trivia, technically they can. You can select `$('[id=Container1]').eq(1)` to get the second `#Container1` element (jQuery). I'm **obviously** not suggesting that you **should** do this, just that you **can** :-)

Comment: Ok, but i don't know to handle JQuery, how could I write it instead of this?

<script type="text/javascript">
function appear() {
document.getElementById("Container1").document.display="block";
}
</script>

Comment: @GregoryCh - I would suggest trying to change this or otherwise selecting it as @Joe has mentioned.  If you remove this `.eq(1)` you will have a jQuery group of both objects.

Comment: Can someone syntax all this code here?

Comment: @richieahb Nobody should **ever** use the code I posted, it's just there because it works, not because it should be used. Duplicate IDs is flat out #doingitwrong ;-)

Comment: how can I set display block with this code?

Comment: @GregoryCh setting "display: block" on a div with no other styles or classes will do precisely nothing as a div is a block level element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to **CSS** change it to:

```
div#parent > div:first-child > div:first-child {
display:none
}
```

`:first-child` does not specify its **immediate** first child, you can use `>` to specify that and avoid second `Container1` from using that style rule.

With this change you can use your existing javascript. and remove `id` from the child div at a later time without affecting this.

http://jsfiddle.net/oz5g3bxs/

> And of course, use unique `id` as already mentioned by *everyone*

Answer (score 0):

If you *can't* change the IDs (and I suggest you try), you can use.  This is only relevant if both divs were not set to display block beforehand.

```
function appear() {

    var containers = [];

    var parent = document.getElementById("Container1");

    containers.push(parent);
    containers.push(parent.children[0]);

    for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
        containers[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxsgpeuk/2/

Note this is purely to get it done in your situation as Joe mentioned in the comments: duplicate IDs is just doing it wrong.

Comment: I want to use it in that case:

`<div onclick="appear()" id="child-2">`

So I write it like this?

`<script type="text/javascript">
function vappear() {
var containers = [];

var parent = document.getElementById("Container1");

containers.push(parent);
containers.push(parent.children[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    containers[i].style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>`

Comment: Just wrap the code in the appear function.  See the updated fiddle.

Comment: I tried that, but it displays only the first div#Container1.

I used this CSS code to hide it (because I wanted to hide the anonymous div also)

`div#parent div:first-child div:first-child {
display: none;
}`

Comment: It doesn't - see the edited fiddle.  It's just because the other div is inside it that it isn't clear.

Comment: This is the real code. I cut some useless lines.

`<div style="border:5px solid #ddd; margin:0; background:#fff; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;width:600px;">
<div id="YoutubeGallerySecondaryContainer1" style="width: 600px; height: 450px; display: block;"><div id="YoutubeGallerySecondaryContainer1" style="width:600px;height:450px;"><div id="ygplayerapiid_1api"></div><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="youtubegalleryplayerid_1" data="http://www.youtqTiqr5c" width="600" height="450"></object></div></div>
</div>`