# Javascript - get id inside table

Tags: javascript, html-table

How do I output the ID names `ok1`, `ok2`, `ok3` inside a Javascript function?

```
<table>
        <tr>
                <td id="col1"><a id="ok1" href="javascript:void(0);">click</a></td>
                <td id="col2"><a id="ok2" href="javascript:void(0);">click</a></td>
                <td id="col3"><a id="ok3" href="javascript:void(0);">click</a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

for example `alert(something);` outputs `ok1`

Comment: You should set onclick="somehting(this)" and inside the function you will have a reference to the anchor.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have multiple ids per element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "getting the id of ok1"

Comment: Have you tried something? This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @DanielRosano I want to get  all the IDs (`ok1`, `ok2`, `ok3`) inside a javascript function

Comment: you can use javascript function getAttribute('id')

Comment: @DanielRosano Sorry, but I meant I needed to output the name of the ID inside a javascript function. like: `alert(something);` outputs `ok1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are activating a handler directly on that element, such as `onclick` you can just do `this.id`, meaning get the `id` attribute of the element:

```
document.getElementById("ok1").onclick = function(){
    console.log(this.id);
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y1e448zy/) - Click the first item, at the id will be shown in the console. The same approach can be done with the other two elements.

**Edit** To simply get all the elements of `<a>` inside a table you can do this:

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr td a");
for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
    console.log(children[i].id);
}
```

Note I've changed the HTML, as you might not want to do this for all your tables. So I've added an id to it:

```
<table id="myTable"> ... </table>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y1e448zy/1/)

Comment: Would you mind reading the question again.. I added a few details and re-explained the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all the `a` tags and loop over it getting the attribute `id` in the function:

```
(function () {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
     console.log(links[i].getAttribute('id'));   
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the id is used as a CSS Selector in your .css file you can get the id "ok1" by doing

```
#ok1 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I needed the `ok1` value.

Comment: would you please read the question again, I edited the description

Answer (score 0):

use **onClick** event

`<td id="col1"><a id="ok1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickFun(this)">click</a></td>`

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0Ho9Ie5kBwaR8Q4Ff0Z?p=preview)

Comment: do you mind reading the question again, I added a few details.

Answer (score 0):

ok see this Code it's work perfect. Hope you satisfy....

```
var parent_ = this_.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("a");

for(var i=0; i<parent_.length; i++)
{
  alert(parent_[i].getAttribute("id"));
}
```

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0Ho9Ie5kBwaR8Q4Ff0Z?p=preview)