# Javascript Problems with .push in a Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pretty new to Javascript and JQuery.

Currently right now I'm trying to use `.push` inside my function.
This should be triggered when a person clicks on a link, and add 1 to my array. After clicking on the click on the link I take a look at the variable `pointTotal`, and find that there is nothing in the array.

If anyone can I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Javascript

var pointTotal = [];

$("#pointOne").click(function() {
    pointTotal.push(1);
});



HTML

  <div class ="quizSectionStress container-fluid">
    <div class="rowOne rowStyle">

      <div class = "answers col-xs-1 col-md-1">
        <div class="btn-group questionGroups">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Answer <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#" id="questionOneOne pointOne" name="questionOneOne" value="1"><label>1</label></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="questionOneTwo pointTwo" name="questionOneTwo" value="2"><label>2</label></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="questionOneThree pointThree" name="questionOneThree" value="3"><label>3</label></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="questionOneFour pointFour" name="questionOneFour" value="4"><label>4</label></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="questionOneFive pointFive" name="questionOneFive" value="5"><label>5</label></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="questionOneSix pointSix" name="questionOneSix" value="6"><label>6</label></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the JS, can you include your HTML in the question?

Comment: What if you use `var pointTotal = new Array();` instead of `var pointTotal = [];`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván please don't encourage the use of `new Array()`; the array literal, `[]`, is almost always preferable.

Comment: Alejandro, `[]` is the recommended way to declare an array, `new Array()` is obsolete

Comment: @royhowie yeah it was just in case (maybe browser implementations may vary, but they shouldn't). Another option (again, **maybe**) is that he isn't declaring inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`?

Comment: That's definitely a possibility

Comment: *"After clicking on the click on the link I take a look at the variable `pointTotal`,"*  How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm using console.log in my console on my browser to see if the array had 1 .push to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring all your variables and events when the DOM is ready:

```
<!-- html... head... jQuery inclusion... -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var pointTotal = [];

        $('#pointOne').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Just in case it's an anchor/submit/whatever..
            pointTotal.push(1);
            alert('pointTotal count so far: ' + pointTotal.length);
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- blah blah... more html -->
```

This is because your element with the `pointOne` id will not be in the DOM before it is ready, so the `click` event will not be attached to it.

Comment: You are correct I had it outside of the DOM ready, but when I I place it when the DOM is ready I can't seem to access the variable pointTotal anymore. I'm going to update my question and put my HTML in there.

Comment: @ndglover21 as far as I can see, your HTML is wrong (for example, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)... first learn HTML and then mess with Javascript/jQuery...

Comment: Thanks that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your code...link with jquery file

```js
var pointTotal = [];

$("#pointOne").click(function(){
pointTotal.push(1);
$("#show").text(pointTotal);
//console.log(pointTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="pointOne">Click</button>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, but when I try to console log pointTotal it is still blank.