# copy text from one div to other div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="noty">Hello</div>
<div id="noty">World</div>
<div id="noty">Nation</div>

<div id="textArea"></div>

$("#noty").click(function() {
    $("#textArea").html($("#noty").html());
});
```

I'm using this to copy text from one div to other by onclick function. But this is not working. It's only working on the first div. Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: You cant have multiple elements with same `id` attribute. Use `class` or `data-id` instead

Comment: Suppose I have 50 divs . How would I do that ?

Comment: Why would the number of divs matter? You'd put them on 50 divs the same way you put them on 3 divs.

Comment: I  not answering the question directly but use angularjs. It makes a lot these things easier without a lot of js coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<div class="noty">Hello</div>
<div class="noty">World</div>
<div class="noty">Nation</div>

<div id="textArea"></div>

<script>
$(".noty").click(function() {
    $("#textArea").html($(this).html());
});
</script>
```

https://jsbin.com/giqilicesa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hey, If i use <input id="textArea"> it isn't working

Comment: @niranjankumar then `$("#textArea").val($(this).text());`

Answer (score 2):

Like this.

```js
$(".noty").click(function(e) {
    $("#textArea").html(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="noty">Hello</div>
<div class="noty">World</div>
<div class="noty">Nation</div>

<div id="textArea"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  `var s = ''; $('.noty').each(function () {s += $(this).html();}); $('#textarea').html(s);` but change your divs to use class="noty" instead of id. The id should be unique.

Comment: This would be all three divs btw

Answer (score 1):

At first, [you must not use multiple id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids). And another problem is [sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle) providing jQuery as a selector engine [returns result to use `getElementById`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L244). It means even if you've declared multiple ids, you'll get just only one id element. When consider those problems, you can get over this problem to follow this way:

```
<div class="noty">Hello</div>
<div class="noty">World</div>
<div class="noty">Nation</div>

<div id="textArea"></div>
<script>
var $noty = $('.noty');
var $textarea = $('#textArea');
$noty.click(function () {
  var text = Array.prototype.map.call($noty, function (el) {
    return $(el).html();
  }).join(' ');

  $textarea.html(text);
});
</script>
```