# Uncaught type error for input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I am trying to upload the file but i have to get the file to upload it but I am unable to do so as I am getting this error

> main.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
function upload() {
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "includes/upload.php";
    var file = document.getElementById("filename").value;
    var image = document.getElementById("image").value;
    var span = document.querySelector('#uploadPreview[style]'),
        a = window.getComputedStyle(span, null).transform,
        b = window.getComputedStyle(span, null).transformOrigin;
    val = 'transform:' + a + ';transform-origin:' + b + ';backface-visibility: hidden;';

    var vars = "style=" + val + "&image=" + image + "&filename=" + file;

    data.open("POST", url, true);
    data.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    data.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (data.readyState == 4 && data.status == 200) {
            var return_data = data.responseText;
            document.getElementById("comment_box").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

    data.send(vars);
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align:center;">
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" id="image" name="image" style="margin:auto;" />
    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
    <input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="<?php if(!empty($data['profile_pic'])) { echo $data['profile_pic'];} ?>" />
    <button type="button" name="update_picture" class="btn_form" onclick="upload();">Update Picture</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What dose line 71 in your main.js script contain? provide JSFiddle if possible please.

Comment: var image = document.getElementById("uploadImage").value;

Comment: actualy i just noticed that there is a duplicate id in your html and you cant do that

Comment: Your code is working fine bro. Just put the scripts before closing tag of body.

Comment: @VladimirDrenovski Really ?? where ??

Comment: Puting the code before the body closing tags is indeed a solution, yet again have to id attribute's is not a valid html

Comment: yes I removed that got fine but unable to upload the image and php is getting file to be empty

Comment: the javascript worked bro but php is unable to retreive it may be i will post another question ut can you let e is it the right way to get the file to be uploaded $_FILES['image']

Comment: $_FILES['image'] is giving me as undefined index it means not getting the file

Comment: $_FILES['image'] when i chage this to $_POST['image'] it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 id's here:

```
 <input id="uploadImage" type="file" id="image" name="image" style="margin:auto;" />
```

Try using just to one id.

You cant have both, you can reference this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids).