# clicking on the link not opening the menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

- I am trying to open the menu items on clicking on click here link.
- My fiddle link is as below link

  [link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/vssJr/5/)
- This link should work like toggle on clicking. Please help with this `enter code here`

Comment: It is working fine for me. what is your problem exactly?

Comment: have you not need toggle? or explain your problem..

Comment: You saw the big, red warning about posting a [mcve] **in your question** when linking to jsFiddle, yet you thought that it didn't apply to you and you'd just try and get around it by highlighting meaningless text as code. Please do as you were asked.

Comment: please check now, link is updated, tried using toggle call is going to click function but menu not expanding !!!

Comment: copy your `jsfiddle fiddle` code here in your question

Comment: pls check link  ---> http://jsfiddle.net/vssJr/155/    @anuj

Comment: @sivashanker http://jsfiddle.net/vssJr/156/

Comment: remove this id `filter-panel2` from html and its work

Comment: pls help in fixing in the fiddle .........

Comment: @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy issue is resolved , i have seen u have removed 'filter-panel2' class. what is causing the problem

Comment: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevanuj/vssJr/160/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use two or multiple `ID(s)` on one html element(tag)..why you can not do this read on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

so finally your code:

```
<div class="cart_clas" >
 <div id="showAll">

   <a href="#">Click here</a>
        </div>
   <!-- menu !-->
  <div class="filter-panel1" id="menu_rewards" style="display:none; ">

  <div class="row" style="float:right;">
  <div class="Shop_by">Shop by Categories</div>
  <div class="hotel_menu">Deals & Offers</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Mobile, Tablets & Accessories</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Laptops & Peripherals</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Men Fashion</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Women Fashion</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Home Decor & Kitchen</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Personal & Health Devices</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Home And Kitchen Appliances</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Tv & Entertainment Devices</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Camera, Dslrs & Accessories</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Coupons & Discounts</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Baby & Kids</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Beauty & Health</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Stationery & Office Supplies</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Sports & Fitness</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Car & Bike Accessories</div>
    <div class="hotel_menu">Gifts & Hobbies </div>
  </div>      
 </div>
   <!-- menu !-->
</div>
```

and **Jquery**:

```
$(function() {
 $('#showAll').click(function(){  //Adds click event listener  
    $('#menu_rewards').show(); // Toggles visibility.
  });
});
```

Comment: what was the issue ?

Comment: you are using two `id` on one element  here '<div class="filter-panel1" id="filter-panel2 menu_rewards" style="display:none; ">'

Comment: i can use 2 unque names in single id right  like <div id="identifier1 selector1" />