# Background-image doesn't show up in a div

Tags: html, css, background, show

It doesn't even show up in the Chrome Inspector. I am doing something wrong but don't know what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trio - Bootstrap Responsive Agency/Portfolio HTML5 Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- CSS & Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <!-- scripts -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id=="container header_div">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS is:

```
body {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;}
header {height: 100vh;}
#header_div {
    background-image: url(../images/header_background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have added all of the background-properties in the css and the div has a size.

My file structure is like this:
[image]

Comment: Try `background-image: url('images/header_background.jpg');`. You also have a typo in `<div id=="container header_div">`. Only one `=`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but it doesn't work.
[link]http://imgur.com/a/pdrbw

Comment: You can't assign multiple ID's to an element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exist `<div id="container header_div">` in you css, change to `<div id="header_div">`

```css
body {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;}
header {height: 100vh;}
#header_div {
    background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trio - Bootstrap Responsive Agency/Portfolio HTML5 Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- CSS & Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <!-- scripts -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="header_div">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I've managed to show it using your corrections to the HTML and this CSS:

`body {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;}
header {height: 100vh;}
#header_div {
 background-image: url('../images/header_background.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 2):

I see several things that can cause the issue:

1. There is double equal here: `<div id=="container header_div">`. Should
   be single. In addition, I see two words in the id separated by
   space. ID's cannot be chained like classes, and this is not a valid
   syntax. Since you style #header_div, the id attribute on the div
   should be id = "header_div".
2. The relative path to the image starts with two dots. As a result, you step out of the current directory. Since your images folder is in
   the same directory as the page.html, the filepath should be:
   url(/images/header_background.jpg);
3. To see the image you would need to declare the height in the #header_div element as well.

By doing this, I was able to see a background image in my test. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue like this before. This is what I did. I set the div background to just this `background: url("./images/header_background.jpg");`

Comment: I believe that since it is relative to the location of the css it should be ../images/header_background.jpg in my case but it doesn't work. :(