# Why div not show/hide on select options in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide a specific div when I select an option from select drop-down.
**For example**
When document load no div will show
When we select 1 option then `OneLevel` will show
When we select 2 option then `TwoLevel` will show
When we select 1 option then `ThreeLevel` will show

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#Level").hide();
function WorkflowLevel(obj) {
    var selectBox = obj;
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

     $("#Level").hide();

    switch (selected) {
    case '0':
        $("#Level").hide();
        break;
    case '1':
        $("#Level").hide();
        $("#Level#OneLevel").show();
        break;
    case '2':
        $("#Level").hide();
        $("#Level#TwoLevel").show();
        break;
    case '3':
        $("#Level").hide();
        $("#Level#ThreeLevel").show();
        break;
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="WorkflowLevel" class="form-control" name="show_text_area" onchange="WorkflowLevel(this)">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="Level OneLevel">1</div>
<div id="Level TwoLevel">2</div>
<div id="Level ThreeLevel">3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can an element have 2 ids?

Comment: You can't write id like this "Level OneLevel". You can write in class like that.

Comment: If id contains spaces, it is not legal HTML. You shouldn't expect this to work. Here is the relevant section of the HTML 4.01 specification.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `switch` case. You can use index position and toggle visibility accordingly.

```js
$(".Level").hide();

function WorkflowLevel(obj) {
  var selected = $("option:selected", obj).index();
  $(".Level").hide();
  selected && $(".Level:eq(" + (selected - 1) + ")").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="WorkflowLevel" class="form-control" name="show_text_area" onchange="WorkflowLevel(this)">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="Level OneLevel">1</div>
<div class="Level TwoLevel">2</div>
<div class="Level ThreeLevel">3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for right answer. Its working fiine.  Only one issue is that when i select first option "Select" then it show 3rd div.

Comment: @SunilKumar Thanks for pointing it out. Have rectified it. :-)

Comment: I use this code and now its working -    `function WorkflowLevel(obj) {
  var selected = $("option:selected", obj).index();
  if(selected==0)
  $(".Level").hide();
  else
  $(".Level").hide().eq(selected-1).show();
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multiple ID is possible for one element, you should use class="level" and id on number like id="OneLevel" or just id="One" and in your hide/show selector use something like $(".level#One").hide();

For more details on multiple id: [Can an html element have multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

Answer (score 0):

There are few defects in both the html & js
It is awkward when you write id as `id="Level OneLevel"` .`id` need to be unique.

Use `Level` as common class . Use this class to hide all the div
`#Level#TwoLevel` & etc is wrong. There is no DOM element with `id` this

**JS**

```
    $(".Level").hide();
    
    function WorkflowLevel(obj) {
      var selectBox = obj;
      var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    
      $(".Level").hide();
    
      switch (selected) {
        case '0':
          $(".Level").hide();
      

    break;
    case '1':
      $(".Level").hide();
      $("#OneLevel").show();
      break;
    case '2':
      $(".Level").hide();
      $("#TwoLevel").show();
      break;
    case '3':
      $(".Level").hide();
      $("#ThreeLevel").show();
      break;
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="OneLevel" class="Level">1</div>
<div id="TwoLevel"  class="Level">2</div>
<div id="ThreeLevel"  class="Level">3</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0w6w8t0w/)

Comment: Why have you not made a snippet? Assuming you have specifically not made one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to write it with significantly less painful rewriting.  We use custom attribute called `showId` to show the proper box by matching it up with the `.val()` of our `WorkFlowLevel` selection.  It will make it a lot easier to add more items.

```js
$("#WorkflowLevel").change(function () {
  $(".Level").hide()
  $("[showId="+$(this).val()+"]").show();
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="WorkflowLevel" class="form-control" name="show_text_area">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="Level" showId="1">1</div>
<div class="Level" showId="2">2</div>
<div class="Level" showId="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't give same `id` to multiple divs, these should be unique.
Use `class` instead, below is am example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".lvl").hide();
  $("#WorkflowLevel").on('change', function(){
    $(".lvl").hide();
    $("#Level"+$(this).val()).show();
  })
  
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="WorkflowLevel" class="form-control" name="show_text_area" >
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="Level1" class="lvl">1</div>
<div id="Level2" class="lvl">2</div>
<div id="Level3" class="lvl">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".Level").hide();

$("#WorkflowLevel").change(function() {
  $(".Level").hide();

  var id = $("option:selected", this).val()

  $(".Level").filter(function() {

    return $(this).attr("data-id") == id;
  }).show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="WorkflowLevel" class="form-control" name="show_text_area">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="Level OneLevel" data-id="1">1</div>
<div class="Level TwoLevel" data-id="2">2</div>
<div class="Level ThreeLevel" data-id="3">3</div>
```

1. Add data-attribute that corresponds to the value of options
2. Change `ID` to `Class` of div `Level` ID should be unique
3. Use filter to select the div that has data attribute equal to option selected value