# Hide pop up onclick button

Tags: javascript, css

once we click on `login` , we want to hide the entire pop up box. I tried as below code.

[image]

```
<div class="ajaxlogin-window">
<div id="ajaxlogin-login-window">
<!-- other code -->
<button class="button"  id="send2" id="close" onclick="window.ajaxlogin-login-window()" >
Login
</button>
```

also i tried `onclick="parentNode.remove()"` but it hide only bottom half of pop up. tried lot of other things. so tried to use same code that `close` button is using as below. but nothing worked for me.

close button :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close">Login button</a>
```

[image]

**script**

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        var triggers = {
            login: {
                el    : $$('.ajaxlogin-login'),
                event : 'click',
                window: $('ajaxlogin-login-window'),
                size: {
                    maxWidth: 300
                }
            },
```

Comment: kindly show your `javascript`

Comment: just use jQuery and either trigger a "hidden" class that toggles display: none, or even use it to remove the box entirely. I'd recommend moving to Vue.js where you can link a boolean value to the display value of the box, that way you just switch that value to on or off and Vue handles everything for you.

Comment: [Every element should only have ONE `id` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

Comment: @caramba thanks for link, can i hide with help of `onclick`....

Comment: Is this even valid JavaScript, `onclick="window.ajaxlogin-login-window()"`? Shoudn't that be `onclick="window.ajaxlogin_login_window()"`?

Comment: @RichardMauritz sorry for that, i tried as you suggested.... but no luck......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add id attribute for the parent div

```
<div id="mydiv" class="ajaxlogin-window">
```

now use this script

```
function hide() {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none';
}
```

then add the onclick event to your button like this

```
<button class="button"  id="send2" onclick="hide()" >
Login
</button>
```

this should work

Comment: i followed exactly as you said, than after i click on `login` , it hided the `login` button , but i need to hide complete pop up in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

Comment: Can you give me a link or fiddle for your work ? @user5348fh8y5

Comment: there is a problem with the link it doesn't open, are you sure this website doesn't require registration ? @user5348fh8y5

Comment: Please try to change the function name e.g. `hideWindow()`

Comment: thanks, it worked , but it not allowing me to click on `add to cart` buttton if i click on login button   http://prnt.sc/f10935   , but if i use the `close` buttton, than i can able to add product to cart.....  http://prnt.sc/f1092o ,  is it any `z index` issue ?

Comment: try to put this script instead the one you are using 
`function hideWindow() {
    document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('ajaxlogin-mask').style.display = 'none';

}`

Comment: this is magento project, did you worked on magento before ?

Comment: Welcome anytime :)
and nope I've never been working on magento.

Answer (score 0):

Add display:none on main div of popup from js when you click button.

```
$(document).('on','click',function(){
 <div id="div1">//your main popup div like this
 document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
})
```

Comment: Thanks & sorry for late reply, i followed your answer in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-5.html) , after i click on `login` , it hided the login button , but i need to hide complete pop up in link , lease upload image/add text, than click on save design buttton, you can see pop up.