# input value returns null

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="input-sol form-control" id="focusedInput appendedInput sol" placeholder="Enter number" type="text" required>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-large" id="submit" type="button" onClick="getUserChoice()">Get Images</button>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function getUserChoice() {
      var user_sol = document.getElementById("sol").value;
```

...

When I enter a value and click the button, my function is triggered but in console I get the following error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
      at getUserChoice (index.js:44)
      at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:53)
```

The other values selected from a drop-down list are fine but not for this input.

Comment: I guess you can't have three ids ? `focusedInput appendedInput sol` ?

Comment: The input's `id` isn't `"sol"` (and is, in fact, invalid). You may be confusing the `id` attribute with the `class` attribute, which *can* have multiple values separated by spaces. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id

Comment: You are right! I forgot that you cannot have multiple ids.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getUserChoice() {
  var user_sol = document.getElementById("sol").value;
  console.log(user_sol);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="sol" class="input-sol form-control" placeholder="Enter number" type="text" required>
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-large" id="submit" type="button" onClick="getUserChoice()">Get Images</button>
</div>
```

As mentioned in the comments, your problem is that you have an invalid ID attribute. You can only have 1 ID per element and it must be unique. Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

As you can see, you code works by simply fixing the ID attribute.

Comment: You are right! I forgot that you cannot have multiple ids.

Answer (score 1):

please see following answer [Can an html element have multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

You can not have multiple `id`-s on an html element. The input's id isn't `"sol"` and that's why `document.getElementById("sol")` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` attribute accepts a list of space-separated class names. Classes are designed to represent groups, and elements can be members of multiple groups.

An `id` is a unique identifier, like a social security number. An element can only have one, and no element can share that of another.

`focusedInput` and `appendedInput` sound more like classes than ids. Move them to the class attribute.