# Can we append multiple ids in list items using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this strange requirement where I need to store multiple ids in a list. Can we append multiple ids like this one `id="'+ y.home +'", id="'+ y.away +'", id="'+ y.draw +'"` .... on...

```
<input type="text" id="home_score">
<ul id="cholder"></ul>
```

```js
$.each(data, function(tx,ty) {
  $("ul#cholder").append('<li id="'+ y.home +'"> ' + y.event + '</li>');
    $('ul#cholder').on('click', 'li', function() {
      $('#home_score').val(this.home);
    });
  });
```

Comment: You want to have multiple `id` attributes in the HTML element...? If so, no that's not possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Comment: By the nature of IDs you can only have one. Unless you mean you just want to record each id of different elements as you loop through?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, within the list element. For eg. <li id="'+ y.home +'">..