# Use jQuery to Show/Hide a Form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I would like to show the second text field incl. copy button as soon as i submit the the first text field. how i can hide the second text field and show after submit?

[image]

I tried as following:

HTML:

First Texfield:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" id="source">
<button type="submit" id="submit" id="formButton">Submit</button></td></tr>
```

Second Textfield:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" size="62" id="target" id="form1">
<button onClick="myFunct()" id="form1">Copy</button></td></tr>
```

JQuery:

```
 <script>
  $("#formButton").click(function(){
   $("#form1").toggle();
    });
 </script>
```

Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: So first question. What happens when you submit the first field?  Does it do a form submit?  Does it do ajax and cancel the form submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to submit data to a server normally you should have your inputs and buttons wrapped in a `<form>` tag, so I added one and set it up so that it sends to a live test server. There's also an iframe added as well to display the server's response. The jQuery is simple:

```
$('#main').on('submit', function() {...
```

When `form#main` "hears" a `submit` event (i.e. when the `button[type=submit]` is clicked...

```
$('.row2').removeClass('hide');
```

...Remove the class `.hide` form `tr.row2` which removes the style `display:none`

BTW, ids must be unique. `#form1` is duplicated and there's 2 ids on one button in OP code.

### Demo

```js
$("#main").on('submit', function() {
  $(".row2").removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<form id='main' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='view'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="source" name='source'>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='row2 hide'>
      <td><input type="text" size="62" id="target" name='target'>
        <button type='button'>Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<iframe name='view'></iframe>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you have duplicate IDs on the button (both `submit` and `formButton`). An element **[can only have one ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192066/2341603)**. I've gone with the latter in my example.

Second, you have duplicate `form1` IDs, which is also [**invalid markup**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Markup_validation#ID_already_defined). Simply make use of classes instead.

Then it's just a matter of hiding these elements by default, and showing them on click of the button. I'd recommend `.show()` for this instead of `.toggle()`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$("#formButton").click(function() {
  $(".form1").show();
});
```

```css
.form1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="source">
    <button type="submit" id="formButton">Submit</button>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" size="62" id="target" class="form1">
    <button onClick="myFunct()" class="form1">Copy</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Obsidian Age, thank you for the explanation and support!!