# Why isn't clear button function isn't working?

Tags: javascript, button

The clear button isn't working to clear `list-group history`

```
//html 
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" 
   type="button" 
   id="clear-inputs"
   onclick="clearIt()">
    Clear history 
</button>
<form id="history"></form>
<div class="list-group" id="history"></div>
```

```
//javascript clear button function                           
function clearIt() {
  document.getElementById('history').value = "";
}
```

Comment: There are two elements with ID `history` (which isn't valid anyway as IDs have to be unique). You will then get the first such element, which is an empty `<form>`, and a form doesn't have a `value`. (Note that a `<div>` doesn't have a `value` either, so it's unclear what you really try to do here...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an HTML element have multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need javascript for clear button, you can just use html for clear button only in form tag. Use   for clear.

Here is a simple example: [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset)

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with the same `id` (the `<form>` and the `<div>`). Browsers will render this, but it is invalid html, as the `id` attribute is supposed to be unique to an element. `getElementById()` is going to grab the first element with the designated `id`.

The second problem with your html is that neither `form` or `div` elements have a `value` attribute, so there is nothing for your function to clear. It is unclear from your example which element is supposed to be cleared by your button. For the `<div>`, you could try setting `document.getElementById('yourUniqueId').innerHtml = ""`. That will clear any html inside of the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have two 'history' id's - not a good practice
2. use 'innerhtml' instead of value - will yield much better results. value is better for like inputs like a

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you provide a unique ID for your elements,
2 elements above has the same ID, also the function must be defined before calling it.

- Always check your Console for logging/errors :)