# getElementById returns null though it's at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, getelementbyid

I'm a student who have just started learning web for my course in university. I intend to build a web displaying slider by creating multiple slide divs in javascript.
My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Link ionic icon -->
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <!-- Link css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css">
    <!-- jquery hosted by google -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- icon for title -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/assets/img/titleBar/rimuru.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>Slime Anime</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Start of header -->
        <div id="header">
            <!-- Start of nav bar -->
            <ul class="header__navbar">
                    <li class="header__navbar-li"><a href="#" class="header__navbar-li-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="header__navbar-li"><a href="#" class="header__navbar-li-link">Band</a></li>
                    <li class="header__navbar-li"><a href="#" class="header__navbar-li-link">Tour</a></li>
                    <li class="header__navbar-li"><a href="#" class="header__navbar-li-link">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="header__navbar-li more"><a href="#" class="header__navbar-li-link">
                        More <ion-icon class="down-icon" name="caret-down"></ion-icon></a>
                        <div class="header__navbar-subnav">
                            <a href="#" class="header__navbar-subnav-link">Merchandise</a>
                            <a href="#" class="header__navbar-subnav-link">Extras</a>
                            <a href="#" class="header__navbar-subnav-link">Media</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End of nav bar -->

            <!-- Start of search icon -->
            <div class="header__search">
                <svg class="search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ionicon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <title>Search</title>
                    <path d="M456.69 421.39L362.6 327.3a173.81 173.81 0 0034.84-104.58C397.44 126.38 319.06 48 222.72 48S48 126.38 48 222.72s78.38 174.72 174.72 174.72A173.81 173.81 0 00327.3 362.6l94.09 94.09a25 25 0 0035.3-35.3zM97.92 222.72a124.8 124.8 0 11124.8 124.8 124.95 124.95 0 01-124.8-124.8z"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <!-- End of search icon -->       
        </div>
        <!-- End of header -->

        
        <!-- Start of slider -->
        <div id="slider js__slider">
            
            <!-- using javascript only -->
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- End of slider -->
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/css/slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My js file:

```
// create slide constructor
var parrent = document.getElementById("js__slider");
window.onload = function() {

    function SlideObject(imgUrl, gradient) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        this.gradient = gradient;
    
        // override toString
        SlideObject.prototype.toString = function() {
            return gradient + ", " + "url('" + imgUrl + "') top center / cover  no-repeat;";
        };
    }
    // declare object
    const arr = [
        new SlideObject('/assets/img/slider/slider1.jpeg',
             "radial-gradient(circle, rgba(241,227,142,0.4038209033613446) 0%, rgba(63,143,116,0.4038209033613446) 30%, rgba(10,20,41,0.9024203431372549) 74%)"),
        new SlideObject('/assets/img/slider/slider2.jpeg',
        "radial-gradient(circle, rgba(241,227,142,0.4038209033613446) 0%, rgba(63,143,116,0.4038209033613446) 40%, rgba(10,20,41,0.9024203431372549) 97%)"),
        new SlideObject('/assets/img/slider/slider3.jpeg',
        "linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(241,227,142,0.4038209033613446) 0%, rgba(63,143,116,0.4038209033613446) 46%, rgba(10,20,41,0.9024203431372549) 88%)")
    ];
    
    
    for (aSlideStyle of arr) {
        let aSlide = document.createElement("div");
        
        // this method for adding only 1 class name
        // aSlide.className = "js__slide";
        aSlide.setAttribute("class", "js__slide slide fade");
        aSlide.style.background = aSlideStyle;
        
        if (parrent != null)
            parrent.appendChild(aSlide);
            // document.getElementById("slider").appendChild(aSlide);
        else
            console.log("No");
        // $(".js__slider").appendChild(aSlide);
    
    }
    

    // for changing slides on slider
    let slideIndex = 0;
    changeSlide();
    
    function changeSlide() {
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('js__slide');
    
        // display "none" for all slides b/f displaying next slide
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i ++)
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
    
        // change to next slide
        slideIndex ++;
        if (slideIndex >= slides.length) slideIndex = 0;
    
        slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    
        // 2s for changing slide
        setTimeout(changeSlide, 2000);
    }
}
```

When I create slide divs without using js, the slider works normally.

```
        <!-- Start of slider -->
        <div id="slider js__slider">
            <!-- when using normal html and css -->
            <div class="slide fade js__slide" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(241,227,142,0.4038209033613446) 0%, rgba(63,143,116,0.4038209033613446) 30%, rgba(10,20,41,0.9024203431372549) 74%) ,url('/assets/img/slider/slider1.jpeg') top center / cover no-repeat;">
                <div class="slide__content">
                    <h3 class="slide__content-header">Rimuru Tempest</h3>
                    <p class="slide__content-text">Main, a slime, and a previous human</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide fade js__slide" style="background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(241,227,142,0.4038209033613446) 0%, rgba(63,143,116,0.4038209033613446) 40%, rgba(10,20,41,0.9024203431372549) 97%) ,url('/assets/img/slider/slider2.jpeg') top center / cover no-repeat;">
                <div class="slide__content">
                    <h3 class="slide__content-header">Rimuru And Friend</h3>
                    <p class="slide__content-text">King and government of Jura Tempest Federation</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide fade js__slide" style="background: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(241,227,142,0.4038209033613446) 0%, rgba(63,143,116,0.4038209033613446) 46%, rgba(10,20,41,0.9024203431372549) 88%) ,url('/assets/img/slider/slider3.jpeg') top center / cover no-repeat;">
                <div class="slide__content">
                    <h3 class="slide__content-header">Jura Tempest Federation</h3>
                    <p class="slide__content-text">View of Monster Federation viewed from sky</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- using javascript only -->
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
```

I have tried to fix problem on other sites by adding onLoad, putting file to the bottom of the page, use jquery but the getElementById still returns null.
I used to think that the bug is from aSlide on for loop, but when using console for debugging, I found that it from getElementById.
I still don't know how to fix.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `id="slider js__slider"` means that the ID attribute is `slider js__slider`. Change to `js__slider` if you want to be able to do `.getElementById("js__slider")`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My code is working right now. I cannot believe that the div cannot have 2 ids at the same time.

Comment: No, that's invalid HTML https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids#:~:text=An%20element%20can't%20have,than%20once%20in%20a%20page.